# Javascript DOM SVG Animation Event Handler

Tags: javascript, html, events, svg

I'm animating SVG elements using SMIL. I'm not using CSS animations because I'm not animating CSS properties, and I'm not using Web animations because they're not supported by browsers yet.

I want to trigger an event at the end of the animation. There's a standard event that is used for this ("onend"), so it should just be a matter of adding this to the element.

In Chrome this only seems to work if I use:

```
animation.onend = function(){thing();};
```

In Firefox this only seems to work if I use:

```
animation.addEventListener("end", function(){thing();});
```

- notice the different event name, "onend" doesn't work.

In Safari, nothing works. I've tried both the above, and also

```
animation.setAttribute("onend", function(){thing();});
animation.setAttributeNS(null,"onend", function(){thing();});
animation.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", function(){thing();});
animation.setAttribute("end", "thing();");
```

and all the variants thereof. Everything looks right in the inspector, but nothing fires.

Any clues how to get this working cross-browser?

Answer (score 0):

AS SMIL will be deprecated anyways, and as you now know events are poorly supported. I would suggest to use Web Animations. They are not widely supported yet, but there are JavaScript polyfills you can
use.https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js

Comment: yeah, no. When Web Animations is a standard I'll use it, until then it's basically a random collection of features randomly supported by browsers and randomly polyfilled by random javscript ;) I'd prefer to switch to d3 completely than have to deal with that.

In a couple of years, sure, I'll happily rewrite this code to use Web Animations, but until then I'm steering clear of them.

Comment: well, ok. that sounds reasonable. Then there is still https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation a SMIL Polyfill (on top of Web Animations though)